# Java code reuse with pre compiled class including Main

Tags: java, jar, apache-poi

I downloaded all the `Apache POI` downloadables recently, specifically `poi-examples-3.11-20141221.jar` wherein it includes pre-compiled examples like "How to Use".

The problem is I can't run the pre-compiled classes without Eclipse.

> Specifics: poi-examples-3.11-20141221.jar
>       -> org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel
>           -> XLSX2CSV.class

`XLSX2CSV` is already compiled with `main()` and I just want to simply run it without eclipse.

Links through other tutorials about JAVA Reference Class and Jar in Java will also be helpful.

Im new here so please be gentle.

Comment: Go to folder and run by > java -jar [your jar file name].jar

Answer (score 1):

Run it with the jar on the classpath, but not with the `-jar` option

For example, for the `.xls` to `csv` converter example [XLS2CSVmra](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/examples/XLS2CSVmra.java) you'd do something like:

```
java -classpath poi-3.12-beta1.jar:poi-examples-3.12-beta1.jar org.apache.poi.hssf.eventusermodel.examples.XLS2CSVmra
```

Make sure that all the POI jars you need are on the classpath (.xlsx / XSSF needs more), along with any of their dependencies from the lib directory. See the [POI Components Page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) for details of what jars you need for what

Comment: I will surely try that.